# textarea top alignment with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, textarea, vertical-alignment

I am running into an issue where I need to use a textarea in conjunction with jQuery .autocomplete. I would like the autocomplete text to display at the top of the texarea, but I can't seem to make this happen. Text wants to align at the bottom despite the css being employed:

```
textarea{ display: inline-block;
          text-align: text-top;
        }
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: This is probably because it adds the styles needed as inline. You need to overwrite that. Add "!important" to your css properties. Also, look into "css specificity", to get a better understanding of the issue - if that is the case.

Comment: Firtly, there is nothing like "_text-align: text-top;_" it should be **"vertical-align: top;" or "vertical-align: text-top;"**. Also, can you share more code? because with this much code I don't see any issue even if I do not provide any text alignment property, refer **http://jsfiddle.net/y7fm2sex/**

Comment: Yes thanks, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

> Theming
>
> The autocomplete widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its
>   look and feel. If autocomplete specific styling is needed, the
>   following CSS class names can be used:
>
> ui-autocomplete: The menu used to display matches to the user.
>   ui-autocomplete-input: The input element that the Autocomplete widget
>   was instantiated with.

So you need to use the jquery UI CSS framework to style it.